# How to set Analytics Event in jQuery without a click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, google-analytics

i am trying to set an Analytics Event in jQuery like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var time_to_open=15000;
   if(readCookie('cookie')!='set'){
      setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('#my_animation').animate({left: 0}, 1000);
        createCookie('cookie', 'set', 1);
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'animation', 'started', time_to_open]);
      },time_to_open);  
   }
});
```

this should track how often an animation was shown. But it is not working.
Are _trackEvent only targeting click events? Or what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiEventTracking#_gat.GA_EventTracker_._trackEvent),

1. **category**: animation
2. **action**: started
3. **opt_label**: time_to_open (label for the action)
4. **opt_value**: 15000 (Int value)
5. **opt_noninteraction**: false

Here is the sample:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var time_to_open = 15000;

    if(readCookie('cookie') != 'set') {
        var t = window.setTimeout(function() {

            jQuery('#my_animation').animate({left: 0}, 1000);

            createCookie('cookie', 'set', 1);

            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'animation', 'started', 'time_to_open', time_to_open, false]);

        }, time_to_open);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`_trackEvent` can silently fail if the opt_label parameter is not a string. Either convert `time_to_open` to a string, or pass it as the `opt_value` parameter.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'animation', 'started', undefined, time_to_open]);
```

[(Google Analytics _trackEvent docs)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiEventTracking#_gat.GA_EventTracker_._trackEvent)